# MVC5 web page error (500)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all I am implementing a program to download emails and save it to database. I am binding the content to webgrid and on row click I am opening a view to show the mail content. Every thing works fine, but when I have the content with html tags I am getting web page error as attached can some one help me. This is my code inside the controller

```
public JsonResult GetMessageDetails(string bodyContent)
    {
        ViewBag.bodyContent = bodyContent;
        return Json(bodyContent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a security feature in MVC to prevent [Cross site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

**How Cross site scripting works ?**

Imagine, You are reading some html input and rendering it in your page without encoding like

```
@Html.Raw(Model.SomePropertyWhichHasHtmlContent)
```

Now, instead of posting an answer, what if I posted  this

`"<script>alert('Bazinga!'); window.location.href='http://www.mywebsite.com';</script>"`

When you try to render this html content in your page using the `Html.Raw()` method, user will be redirected to www.mywebsite.com after seeing the alert.

Now in your case, If you trust the input coming to this method, know how to always encode the content while re displaying in a page, and want to override this behavior, you may decorate your action method with `ValidateInput` attribute with value `false`

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult GetMessageDetails(string bodyContent)
{
    ViewBag.bodyContent = bodyContent;
    return Json(bodyContent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```